# Getting input device supported formats with NAudio

Tags: windows, audio, naudio

I would like to use NAudio for a record program, but I'm hitting an unexpected limitation.  NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber) returns a WaveInCapabilities structure, but only a few fields of that structure are public.

In particular I need to know which formats are supported by the device.  That information is in:

private SupportedWaveFormat supportedFormats;

I can change that to public and build NAaudio.dll, but I'm wondering if there is some reason that field is marked private?  Or is there another place I can find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was an example on the web, i edited it, and this works for me to get all the capabilites from different devices (it's quite ugly, but it works...):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
namespace _4ch_stream
{
    class clsRecDevices
    {


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct WaveInCaps
        {
            public short wMid;
            public short wPid;
            public int vDriverVersion;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
            public char[] szPname;
            public uint dwFormats;
            public short wChannels;
            public short wReserved1;
        }

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int waveInGetNumDevs();
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveInGetDevCaps")]
        public static extern int waveInGetDevCapsA(int uDeviceID,
                             ref WaveInCaps lpCaps, int uSize);
        public ArrayList arrLst = new ArrayList();
        //using to store all sound recording devices strings 

        static int devcount = waveInGetNumDevs();
        public static short[] Mid = new short[devcount];
        public static short[] Pid = new short[devcount];
        public static int[] DriverVersion = new int[devcount];
        public static uint[] Formats = new uint[devcount];
        public static short[] Channels = new short[devcount];
        public static short[] Reserved1 = new short[devcount];

        public int Count
        //to return total sound recording devices found
        {
            get { return arrLst.Count; }
        }
        public string this[int indexer]
        //return spesipic sound recording device name
        {
            get { return (string)arrLst[indexer]; }
        }
        public clsRecDevices() //fill sound recording devices array
        {
            int waveInDevicesCount = waveInGetNumDevs(); //get total
            if (waveInDevicesCount > 0)
            {
                for (int uDeviceID = 0; uDeviceID < waveInDevicesCount; uDeviceID++)
                {
                    WaveInCaps waveInCaps = new WaveInCaps();
                    waveInGetDevCapsA(uDeviceID, ref waveInCaps,
                                      Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WaveInCaps)));
                    arrLst.Add(new string(waveInCaps.szPname).Remove(
                               new string(waveInCaps.szPname).IndexOf('\0')).Trim());
                    Mid[uDeviceID] = waveInCaps.wMid;
                    Pid[uDeviceID] = waveInCaps.wPid;
                    Formats[uDeviceID] = waveInCaps.dwFormats;
                    Channels[uDeviceID] = waveInCaps.wChannels;
                    Reserved1[uDeviceID] = waveInCaps.wReserved1;
                    //clean garbage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that worked.  I ended up just making formats public and rebuilding.